# Formulas with free variables in first order language

Tags: first-order-logic

I've some trouble to understand free variable formulas. My problem (well, one of them) is this: from $f(x)$ I infer ($ \forall x f(x)$). On the other hand from ($\forall x f(x)$) I infer $f(x)$. So I conclude that $f(x)$ and ($\forall x f(x)$) are logically equivalent. But logical equivalence is preserved by connectives, so I conclude this: ($f(x) \lor g(x)$) is logically equivalent to $[(\forall x f(x)) \lor (\forall x g(x))]$ and also to $[\forall x (f(x) \lor g(x))]$. But this is false. What is wrong?

Comment: You could say $\forall x \; \phi \; \to \; \exists x \; \phi$, not an unquantified version. Otherwise, you could just say $\forall \forall \; \phi$ (no, this is not a typo, replace $\phi$ with $\forall \; \phi$ in the $\forall \; \phi$) which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Free variables are a bit tricky. They are implicitly universally quantified at the very end.

$F(x)$ indeed has the same truth conditions as $\forall x \mathop. F(x)$, but this does not mean that any occurrence of $F(x)$ can be replaced with $\forall x \mathop. F(x)$.

Take, for example, $\lnot F(x)$. This wff with a free variable is equivalent to the sentence $\forall x \mathop. \lnot F(x)$ and is not equivalent to $\lnot \forall x \mathop. F(x)$.

The problem that you ran into is that, although $(\forall x \mathop. F(x)) \lor (\forall x \mathop. G(x))$ implies $\forall x \mathop. F(x) \lor G(x)$, the converse does not hold.

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. Thank you Gregory for your example with 'not', which is simpler than mine; So, with your example, i can reformulate the question in this way: I presuppose that if a formula f is logically equivalent fo a formula g, then not-f is log.equivalent to not-g; but it seems to me ( maybe I'm wrong) that f(x) is log.equivalent to (for all x f(x)), notwithstanding (not f(x)) is not log.equivalent to (not for all x f(x)). So there is something wrong in one of my two premises (or something in my terminology). You suggest the first is wrong, if I correctly understand.

Answer (score 0):

First, we say that $\forall \; \psi(x) \; \to \; \exists \; \psi(x)$, which we take as a tautology. Now, the problem with saying that $\forall \; \psi(x)$ is equivalent to $\psi(x)$ with free($\psi$)$\; =x$ implies that a closed-forumla is equivalent to a free one.
Hope this helps. Also, another thing that I point out in the comments, if it is true then you could replace the $\psi(x)$ in $\forall \psi(x)$ with another $\forall \, \forall \psi(x)$ which... needless to say, makes little sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I agree with you in the first part. Just I think that (for all x for all x f(x)) actually is a strange formula, but it is well formed , is equivalent to (for all x f(x)) and has no free variable, so it gives me no problem replacing (for all x for all x f(x)) with (for all x f(x)).

Comment: @JosephF Of course it is but it has implications. First, you might be going outside of first-order logic as quantifying over predicates (which are formulae) will run you outside of first-order domain. On a second note, you can do something called *quantifier elimination* where you can find an equivalent free formula for a quantified formula through a strict process, and so it is not totally bogus to say that it is equivalent to free formula, just that this is not *the* formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination (here is a link on it, and you can probably search on MSE for it too...)